# How do i cancel a backgroundworker operation and how to pause/continue a backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a button that start the backgroundworker:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            button1.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
        }
```

A button to cancel the backgroundworker:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
```

The backgroundworker dowork.progresschanged.completed events:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgw = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
            if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Parseanddownloadfiles();
            }
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "Downloading Filename: " + e.UserState.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }
```

And last the method Parseanddownloadfiles()

```
private void Parseanddownloadfiles()
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(mainurl, path_exe + "\\page.html");
            }
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc = hw.Load(path_exe + "\\page.html");
            foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
                if (hrefValue.Contains("US"))
                {
                    string url = "http://www.testing.com" + hrefValue;
                    parsedlinks.Add(url);
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < parsedlinks.Count; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        string filename = parsedlinks[i].Substring(71);
                        client.DownloadFile(parsedlinks[i], filesdirectory + "\\" + filename);
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, filename);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    string error = err.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

The important thing now is to make the cancel to work and then if it's possible to make the pause/continue after it.

Comment: That cancellation won't work because you only check it in the beginning.  It needs to be inside the loop since that is where you want to break out of it.  You should disable the button before starting the worker, and you should only enabled it in the worker's completion event.

Comment: What is the version of .Net Framework you are using ? If you use version >= 4, I can show a solution with tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method int order to check the condition inside the loops into :

```
private void Parseanddownloadfiles()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(mainurl, path_exe + "\\page.html");
    }
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc = hw.Load(path_exe + "\\page.html");
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
    {
        string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
        if (hrefValue.Contains("US"))
        {
            string url = "http://www.testing.com" + hrefValue;
            parsedlinks.Add(url);
        }
        if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
             return;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < parsedlinks.Count &&  bgw.CancellationPending == false; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string filename = parsedlinks[i].Substring(71);
                client.DownloadFile(parsedlinks[i], filesdirectory + "\\" + filename);
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, filename);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string error = err.ToString();
        }
    }
```

If you need to cancel the downloads, my favorite solution would be to use some Tasks and a CancellationTokenSource.

Regards

Comment: This is working but i also need to be able to cancel it when downloading the Main Url. Inside the first using (WebClient... i tried to add after the line client.DownloadFile this: if (bgw.CancellationPending == true)
                    return; but when i click the cancel button it's not effecting it. It does working on the other two cases when i cancel but i need somehow to be abale to cancel in that place too.